# Mysql Update statement to delete duplicates

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique

I would like to make an update on my unique id like replacing white space, but on that case the update statement breaks because of redundant s I tried to make an update as it follows but
 wrong syntax

```sql
UPDATE __cat_product 
SET product_id = REPLACE(product_id,' ','')
ON DUPLICATE KEY DELETE product_id
WHERE product_id LIKE "%A %"
```

how to do this in the right way?

Comment: Think you would need to do this as 2 statements. One to do the updates and one to do the deletes.

Comment: update would not work on duplicate would break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax that is part of an `UPDATE` statement.

I'm having difficulty figuring out what you actually want to do.

You want to update a column in a table, to remove all space characters. And when you tried to run that statement, the statement encountered an error like `Duplicate entry 'foo' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

Assuming that `product_id` is varchar, try this on for size:

```
UPDATE __cat_product t
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(s.product_id) AS product_id
              , REPLACE(s.product_id,' ','')
           FROM __cat_product s
          WHERE s.product_id LIKE '%A %'
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                               FROM __cat_product d
                              WHERE d.product_id = REPLACE(s.product_id,' ','')
                            )
          GROUP BY REPLACE(s.product_id,' ','')
       ) r
    ON r.product_id = t.product_id
   SET t.product_id = REPLACE(t.product_id,' ','')
```

The inline view aliased as **r** gets the values of `product_id` that can actually be updated, because the "updated" product_id value doesn't already exist in the table. And the `GROUP BY` ensures that we're only getting one `product_id` per targeted replacement value.

There may be rows in the table that still match the predicate `product_id LIKE '%A %'`. The spaces cannot be removed from `product_id` column on those rows without throwing a duplicate key exception.

A separate DELETE statement could be used to remove those rows.